# How can I change the CSS of this embed player?

Tags: javascript, css, jplayer

I'm trying to alter the css stylesheet of this embed player, but I'm unable to do it so far...

Here's the default code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var zippywww="81";
    var zippyfile="qHe0GQdg";
    var zippytext="#000000";
    var zippyback="#e8e8e8";
    var zippyplay="#ff6600";
    var zippywidth="100%";
    var zippyauto=false;
    var zippyvol=80;
    var zippywave = "#ffffff";
    var zippyborder = "#cccccc";

    var a = navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera;        
    document.write("<iframe height='92' width='"+zippywidth+"' frameBorder='0' src='http://api.zippyshare.com/api/jplayer_embed.jsp?key="+zippyfile+"&server=www"+zippywww+"&width="+zippywidth+"'></iframe>");

</script>
```

The issue is that the CSS code is located inside the `jplayer_embed.jsp` file, which is called by the `iframe`.

I tried copying the source code of the `.jsp`, saving it into a new local `.jsp` file, so I can inject a different `.css` into it, but the player doesn't load the audio source.

Here's the source code of the `.jsp` (by using 'view page source'):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/css/jplayer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//api.zippyshare.com/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//api.zippyshare.com/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//api.zippyshare.com/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0; width: px;">
        <div class="center" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="jquery_jplayer" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
            <div id="jp_container" class="jp-audio" style="width: -182px;">
                <div class="jp-type-single">
                    <div class="jp-interface">
                        <ul class="jp-controls">
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="jp-time-holder">
                            <span class="jp-current-time"></span>
                            /
                            <span class="jp-duration"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jp-progress" style="width:-82px;">


                                <div onclick="toggleSDHD();" class="hdsdtoggle sd-icon"></div>

                            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                <img src="//.zippyshare.com/wf//file.html" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;">
                                <img src="//.zippyshare.com/images/jplayer/player-overlay.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                                <div class="jp-play-bar" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;"></div>
                            </div>
                                <a href="//.zippyshare.com/v//file.html" target="_blank"><div class="dwnbtn dwn-icon"></div></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-download" style="width:-2px; height: 0px; border-top: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-no-solution">
                        <span>Update Required</span>
                        To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

                zippyhq = false || isFirefox;


                if (isFirefox) {
                    $.each($(".hdsdtoggle"), function (idx, val) {
                            $(val).removeClass("sd-icon").addClass("hd-icon"); 
                    });
                }
                $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
                    ready: function (event) {
                        if (!zippyhq) {
                            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                                m4a: "//.zippyshare.com/audio//0/file.mp3"
                            });
                        } else {
                            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                                m4a: "//.zippyshare.com/audioHQ//0/file.mp3"
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    swfPath: "//api.zippyshare.com/js",
                    supplied: "m4a",
                    wmode: "window",
                    solution: "html, flash",
                    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container"
                });

                toggleSDHD = function () {
                    if (isFirefox) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (zippyhq) {
                        zippyhq = false;
                        $.cookie('zippyhq', "0", {expires:99999, domain: 'zippyshare.com', path: '/'});
                        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            m4a: '//.zippyshare.com/audio//0/file.mp3'
                        });
                        $.each($(".hdsdtoggle"), function (idx, val) {
                            $(val).removeClass("hd-icon").addClass("sd-icon"); 
                        });
                    } else {
                        zippyhq = true;
                        $.cookie('zippyhq', "1", {expires:99999, domain: 'zippyshare.com', path: '/'});
                        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            m4a: '//.zippyshare.com/audioHQ//0/file.mp3'
                        });
                        $.each($(".hdsdtoggle"), function (idx, val) {
                            $(val).removeClass("sd-icon").addClass("hd-icon"); 
                        });
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way that this can be done?

Comment: Can you make your custom .jsp file code point to the URL of the audio source as if it was just running on zippyshare.com/api?

Comment: You should post the code of `jplayer_embed.jsp` file to provide more infomation.

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 That's what I was trying, but it doesn't seem to work... I just added the source code of the .jsp file to my post. And yes, I did have added the domain to the script source url's. They were loaded. But it's not loading the audio file for some reason.

Comment: @Rico just did it!

Comment: @Wex Did you get the cross origin error in devtools when you test your pages. Because you download and serve it locally, I think maybe you will across this error, please have a check.

Comment: @Rico Here's what the console tab shows: `file.html:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
player-overlay.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
file.mp3:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
jplayer_embed.jsp?key=qHe0GQdg&server=www81&width=100%:29 GET file://.zippyshare.com/wf//file.html net::ERR_INVALID_URL
jplayer_embed.jsp?key=qHe0GQdg&server=www81&width=100%:30 GET file://.zippyshare.com/images/jplayer/player-overlay.png net::ERR_INVALID_URL
.zippyshare.com/audio//0/file.mp3:1 GET file://.zippyshare.com/audio//0/file.mp3 net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

Comment: @Wex In those URLs, like `//.zippyshare.com/wf//file.html`, `//.` is invalid, `//` between `wf` and `file.html` is invalid. You can copy those URLs to open it with browser directly to check whether those resource URLs are right or not.

Comment: @Rico Yes, I know. These aren't meant to be static urls..Thus they aren't working. They should change to the values of the variables from the main file (the first code block I posted). I think unfortunately this just can't be run from local server...Btw, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bring changes to it. it will get the CSS from the original site.